# using 2-d array for user login verification

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a assignment and would like to run a for loop to get search the username and password for verification but I can only able to login while using my first set of username and password, can someone please advise?

```
readFile readfile = new readFile();
String tempStrCheck[][] = readfile.checkFile();

for (int row = 0; row < tempStrCheck.length; row++) {
    if (username.equals(tempStrCheck[row][0])) {
        for (int col = 0; col < tempStrCheck[row].length; col++) {
            if (password.equals(tempStrCheck[row][1])) {
                if (type.equals(tempStrCheck[row][2])) {
                    out.println("<script>");
                    out.println("alert('Login Successfully.');");
                    out.println("location='/index.html';");
                    out.println("</script>");
                    return;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like Java more than Javascript..

Comment: This is not `javascript`

Comment: can we have a sample of how your array is structured (without showing actual usernames and passwords of course), because you loop on columns `int col` but never use `col` anywhere in your comparisons

Comment: What do you really want? Just some advise? You don't need to able a question for this. But let's suppose that you're asking for a better code... I would suggest you to put all those values inside a `Map` and then look for the `username` key...

Comment: Did you try debugging it? What went unexpectedly?

Comment: I thought asking for advise would be in a more polite way :'(

Comment: we could advise you with an array sample maybe, from what i see from what we've got, either each username has only one password and type, and so the second loop is useless (because you access directly to `[1]` and `[2]`), either they have multiple ones, and without a look at it, cannot answer

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong (ignoring `type` as I'm not sure what that is) - https://ideone.com/6R28Lu

Comment: in the password txt, it is stored something like this

Ira1,2213212,Customer
Ira2,123123dasdad,Administrator
Ira3,qweqcsfwweq,Customer

Comment: So, from your data sample, this loop is useless an can be removed: `for (int col = 0; col < tempStrCheck[row].length; col++) {`, and I see no reason why the other users than the first wouldn't pass the tests. Maybe a type problem so that `equals` gives a wrong result?

Comment: I think I know which part goes wrong... seems tempStrCheck[row][0] , tempStrCheck[row][1] and  tempStrCheck[row][2] are not equals to Ira2,123123dasdad,Administrator,

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think why the username and password are not acceptable because the program just get null, null, null on the rest of the arraylist.
Here are my coding

```
     File file = new File("password.txt");

  FileReader read = new FileReader(file); 
  String[][] matrix = new String[5000][5000];   
  int a1=0, a2=0;

  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
  String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){ //file reading
            String[] values = line.split(",");
        for (String str : values)
        {
                matrix[a1][a2]=str;
                System.out.println(matrix[a1][a2]);
                a2++;  
        }
        a1++;
        a2=0; //must added after doing one loop of a1, otherwise a2 will keep counter.
    }
```

is there any parts goes wrong?

Comment: You never reset a2 to 0.

Comment: so what do i do to make it run normally...?

Comment: Problem has been fixed, thanks Max! Your advise really helps me a lot.